# Use a single colour for range of values and include inequality symbol on colorkey levelplot R

Tags: r, maps, raster, levelplot

I have 4 `rasters` with values spanning both positive and negative scales. For the 4 `rasters`:
1) I will like to use just one color break on both ends of the `colorkey` for all values outside the range +/-20, say. This is because I am more interested in the intra-raster and inter-raster variability of smaller values.

2) How can I specify the labels of the `colorkey` such that they look similar to: `at=c(<=-20, -10,   0  , 10 , >=20)`. The most important thing here is how to include the inequality sign in the `colorkey` label

Reproducible example and sample code shown below. The image shows my actual data display using `levelplot` function.

```
library(raster)
library (colorRamps)
set.seed(100)
ras <- raster(ncol=100, nrow=100)
ras1 <- setValues(ras, (1:ncell(ras))/100 + rnorm(ncell(ras)) - 50)

s=stack(ras1,ras1,ras1,ras1)


color_levels=14 #the number of colors to use
max_abolute_value=max(abs(c(cellStats(s, min), cellStats(s, max)))) #what is the maximum absolute value of raster?
color_sequence=unique(round(seq(-max_abolute_value,max_abolute_value,length.out=color_levels+1),0))

myColorkey <- list(at=color_sequence,space = "bottom", ## where the colors change 
                   labels=list(axis.line = list(col = NA),at=color_sequence,rot=0,cex=0.9,font=6,
                               fontface=1),height=1,width=1.4)

col1 <- colorRampPalette(c("darkred", "red3","red",
                           "gray96",  "lightskyblue", "royalblue3", 
                           "darkblue"))

levelplot(s,contour=F, layout=c(4, 3),  col.regions = col1,colorkey=myColorkey,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for (i), you could simply `reclassify` the raster layers and set all values smaller than -20 (or larger than 20) e.g. to -20.5 (or 20.5). I guess this makes sence since you are not interested in smaller or larger values anyway. As for (ii), I would recommend using `spplot` and modify the colorkey as detailed in `?levelplot` (from package **lattice**). Note that the desired labels can easily be inserted using Unicode characters (e.g., [greater than or equal to](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2265/index.htm)).

```
 ## reclassify data
m_rcl <- matrix(c(-100, -20, -20.5, 
                  20, 100, 20.5), 
                byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)

s_rcl <- reclassify(s, m_rcl)

## colors
library(RColorBrewer)
cols <- brewer.pal(6, "RdBu")
cols <- rev(cols)
cols <- colorRampPalette(cols)

## display data
spplot(s_rcl, col.regions = cols(100), at = seq(-21, 21, 1),
       colorkey = list(space = "bottom", 
                       labels = list(at = seq(-20, 20, 10), 
                                     labels = c("\u2264 -20", 10, 0, 10, "\u2265 20"))))
```

[image: spplot]

Comment: thanks for providing an insightful solution. The reclassification looks great. I am trying to factor your suggestions into my code above but I can't get it just right. 
`m_rcl <- matrix(c(-Inf, -100, -100.5,100, Inf, 100.5), byrow = TRUE, col= 3);s_rcl <- reclassify(s, m_rcl)`.You can generate new s to suite the new `m_rcl`. I need `colour_levels=14 or 15 maximum`. Within `levelplot` above, how can I use the `labels` in `colour_sequence` such that the value `+/- 321` in the sample plot above is replaced by `<=100 and >=100`?

Comment: Following @fdetsch suggestion this works for as expected:

Answer (score 1):

Following @fdetsch suggestion this works for me:

```
m_rcl <- matrix(c(-375, -100, -100.5, 
                  100, 484, 100.5), 
                byrow = TRUE, ncol = 3)

s_rcl <- reclassify(s, m_rcl)


levelplot(s_rcl,contour=F,margin=FALSE,xlab=NULL,ylab=NULL,par.strip.text=list(cex=0), scales = list(x=x.scale, y=y.scale),
          col.regions = col1, at = seq(-110, 110,20),layout=c(4, 3),index.cond=list(c( 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12)),
          colorkey = list(space = "bottom", 
                          labels = list(at = seq(-100, 100, 20), rot=0,cex=0.9,font=6,fontface=1,
                                        labels = c("\u2264 -100", "-80",  "-60" , "-40"  ,"-20" ,  
                                                   "0" ,  "20" ,  "40" ,  "60" ,  "80" ,  "\u2265 100")),height=1,width=1.4))
```

Thanks very much.